# MongoDB connectionString not working from Ruby within Puppet

Tags: ruby, mongodb, puppet

I used the same connectionstring in the terminal and it's working ok.
But from Ruby I get error output when `vagrant provision` runs

```
mongo admin -u 'vaga' -p 'vaga' --authenticationDatabase admin  --host 127.0.0.1:27018 --eval 'db.version()'
```

this is the error output:

```
==> default: Error: Could not prefetch mongodb_user provider 'mongodb': Execution of '/usr/bin/mongo admin -u vaga -p vaga --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27018 --eval db.version()' returned 1: 2015-02-06T20:55:25.023+0100 Error: 4 Missing expected field "pwd" at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
==> default: exception: login failed
==> default: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/mongo admin -u vaga -p vaga --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27018 --eval db.version()' returned 1: 2015-02-06T20:55:25.096+0100 Error: 4 Missing expected field "pwd" at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
==> default: exception: login failed
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[heffervesser]/Mongodb_user[vaga]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/mongo admin -u vaga -p vaga --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27018 --eval db.version()' returned 1: 2015-02-06T20:55:25.096+0100 Error: 4 Missing expected field "pwd" at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
==> default: exception: login failed
```

this is the ruby code

```
 # Mongo Command Wrapper
  def self.mongo_eval(cmd, db = 'admin')
    if mongorc_file
        cmd = mongorc_file + cmd
    end

    mongoauth = Facter.value(:mongoauth)
    out = mongo([db, mongoauth, '--quiet', '--host', get_conn_string, '--eval', cmd])


    out.gsub!(/ObjectId\(([^)]*)\)/, '\1')
    out
  end

  def mongo_eval(cmd, db = 'admin')
    self.class.mongo_eval(cmd, db)
  end
```

Comment: This kind of issue "running in terminal but not in my script or software" are due to missing environnement variable. Perhaps your ruby software doesn t use the sane path variable.